# Partial sum over an array given a list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D matrix and I need to sum a subset of the matrix elements, given two lists of indices `imp_list` and `bath_list`. Here is what I'm doing right now:

```
s = 0.0
for i in imp_list:
    for j in bath_list:
        s += K[i,j]
```

which appears to be very slow. What would be a better solution to perform the sum?

Comment: It's slow because it is an n^2 algorithm. It is what it is. You have to visit all those positions one way or another.

Comment: How big is imp_list, and how big is bath_list?

Comment: using numpy can be very helpful here. Here is the link http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.sum.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with large arrays, you should get a huge speed boost by using NumPy's own indexing routines over Python's `for` loops.

In the general case you can use `np.ix_` to select a subarray of the matrix to sum:

```
K[np.ix_(imp_list, bath_list)].sum()
```

Note that `np.ix_` carries some overhead, so if your two lists contain consecutive or evenly-spaced values, it's worth using regular slicing to index the array instead (see `method3()` below).

Here's some data to illustrate the improvements:

```
K = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)
imp_list = range(100)  # [0, 1, 2, ..., 99]
bath_list = range(200) # [0, 1, 2, ..., 199]

def method1():
    s = 0
    for i in imp_list:
        for j in bath_list:
            s += K[i,j]
    return s

def method2():
    return K[np.ix_(imp_list, bath_list)].sum()

def method3():
    return K[:100, :200].sum()
```

Then:

```
In [80]: method1() == method2() == method3()
Out[80]: True

In [91]: %timeit method1()
10 loops, best of 3: 9.93 ms per loop

In [92]: %timeit method2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 884 µs per loop

In [93]: %timeit method3()
10000 loops, best of 3: 34 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, perfectly what I needed, it saved me a lot of time, and I could also re-use your methods in other functions.